# class name based on string in variables in vue.js

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I want to add a dynamic and a static class to an element.
The following code doesn't work.

```
var string = 'hugo';

<div v-bind:class="{ staticClass: true, dynamicClass: string }">
    {{ string }}
</div>
```

This is the expected output I would like to accomplish.

```
<div class="staticClass hugo">hugo</div>
```

What I get instead is the following

```
<div class="staticClass dynamicClass">hugo</div>
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As referenced [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax) you can pass an array to `v-bind:class` to apply multiple classes to your `div`. Because you have one dynamic class, it would make sense to use the object syntax inside array syntax.

In your case it would be something like that

```
<div v-bind:class="[{staticClass: true}, string]">
    {{ string }}
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4f8a0k3v/)

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to do this:

1. Use an array for dynamic class binding:

```
<div :class="['staticClass', dynamicClass]">
    {{ string }}
</div>
```

2. Use an object and a JavaScript dynamic property name (you ccan create a method that returns this object and bind to it for convenience) :

```
<div :class="{
    'staticClass': true,
    [dynamicClass]: true
}">
    {{ string }}
</div>
```

3. But the best way, in my opinion, is to combine a static class property and a Vue dynamic binding. The dynamic binding (`:class`) can contain an array, object, a string, or a variable referring to one of the three:

```
<div class="staticClass" :class="dynamicClass">
    {{ string }}
</div>
```

See [Vue 3 Documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html) or [This Article](https://michaelnthiessen.com/dynamically-add-class-name).